# how to start selendroid inspector and find the webelement in UI

Tags: selendroid

how to start selendroid inspector i am getting error "Selendroid inspector can only be used if there is an active test session running. To start a test session, add a break point into your test code and run the test in debug mode.

Comment: Start your test in debug mode (like in eclipse put break point). Once the selenium server loads it in device, it will generate a session for your tests. Take that url and paste it in your browser, you will get the screen u r looking for...

Answer (score 1):

1. Run your test case in debug mode and add breakpoints to the test method.
2. Then open your browser and http://localhost:4444/inspector

You can inspect elements.